# Yii Model attributes showing null/blank values

Tags: php, yii, model, frameworks

I was working on a simple form in Yii. I was able to access model attributes values before.

But now I can't, because it's showing blank/null.

I don't know what's the problem and how to solve this. any help will be appreciated. 
Thank You.

here's the form code.

```
    <div class="span4">
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'testform',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
    )); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sample'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'sample'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'sample'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
    </div>

   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
   </div>
```

here is model's code:

```
     class Questions extends CActiveRecord
    {
        public $sample;

    public function tableName()
    {
          return 'questions';
    }


    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'queid' => 'Queid',
            'question' => 'Question',
                        'sample'=>'sample textfield',
        );
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

        public function getInput()
        {
            $data = $this->sample;
            echo "<script>alert('testing input'".$this->sample."')</script>";
            echo $this->sample;
            return $data;

        }
}
```

And this is controller code for that page:

```
  public function actiontest()
      {
        $model = new Questions();
        $data = "";
          if(isset($_POST["Questions"]))
          {
            $data = $model->getInput();
          }

        $this->render('test',array('model'=>$model,'data'=>$data));
     }
```

Comment: `$model = new Questions();` you made a new model, it's attributes are probably not predifined

Comment: how and where should I define them?

Comment: if you have saved it, maybe load it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller , 
why do you use `$_POST['test']` ?  what is '`test`' here . Your model name is `Questions`

Try

```
if(isset($_POST["Questions"])) {
   $model->attributes = $_POST["Questions"];
   echo $model->sample ; // you will get the value of sample

 }
```

or

if you want the attribute values , you can try this instead of your getInput() ,

```
 $data = $_POST['Questions']['sample'];
```

Comment: its showing error, when I tried self instead of $this, that undefined class constant...

Comment: we usually access attribute values like $this->attribute, in model. but I getting nothing or a blank value. I previously, worked with two other form change password and forgot password. both worked correctly.

Comment: have you tried Questions::sample instead of self::sample ?

Comment: if I use Questions::sample instead of $this->sample. nothing happens its just the same...

Comment: can you show me, the code, that how we usually get user input,with model view and controller.?

Comment: can you do this  if(isset($_POST['Question'])){  print_r($_POST);exit; } in your controller and tell me what the result is ?

Comment: Array ( [Questions] => Array ( [sample] => sdfsdfdsfddfsfff ) [yt0] => ).  this was the result..

Comment: this looks correct only , then what do you want ? if you want to take the values of sample ,  $_POST['Questions']['sample'];  or inside isset($_POST['Questions']) add this  $model->attributes = $_POST['Questions'];  you can get value of  echo $model->sample;

Comment: Thank you so much friend... you saved me today... what was i missing was the $model->attributes = $_POST['Questions'];, this line...

Comment: Glad to help you , i will edit the answer , if this is helpful kindly accept this as correct answer ,it will helpful for others in future.Thanks